# error cannot convert from AsyncTask<String,String,String> to String

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to load a data using JSON from php and then parsing it in android. I'm trying to implement asynctask in this process. And the return is in string. I got an error in 
"Type mismatch : cannot convert from `AsyncTask<String,String,String>` to `String` in

```
    ProsesTampil p = new ProsesTampil();
    xResult = p.execute(urltampil);
```

The `xResult` is supposed to be the string value I got from php. 
Here's the complete codes :

```
public void tampilkanData() {
        try {
            String nama = URLEncoder.encode(Login.usernameP, "utf-8");
            urltampil += "?" + "&nama=" + nama;
            txtNama.setText("");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ProsesTampil p = new ProsesTampil();
        xResult = p.execute(urltampil);

        try {
            parse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


       private void parse() throws Exception {
            //jObject = new JSONObject(xResult);

            JSONArray menuitemArray = new JSONArray(xResult);
            jObject=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String sret="";
            txtBerat.setText(jObject.getString("berat_badan"));
            txtNama.setText(jObject.getString("username"));
       //     txtUsia.setText(jObject.getString("usia"));
            txtTinggi.setText(jObject.getString("tinggi_badan"));
            //System.out.println(jObject.getString("jenis_kelamin").equalsIgnoreCase("female"));
            if(jObject.getString("jenis_kelamin").equalsIgnoreCase("female")){
                radioFemale.setSelected(true);
                radioMale.setSelected(false);
            }else{
                radioMale.setSelected(true);
                radioFemale.setSelected(false);
            }
   }

 public String getRequestData(String UrlTampil){

               String sret="";
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(UrlTampil);
                try{
              HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                  sret =request(response);

                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Gagal "+sret, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                System.out.println(sret);
                return sret;

        }

    class ProsesTampil extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return getRequestData(params[0]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

    }
```

I'm sorry for my bad english. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The propose of an `AsyncTask` is execute some code in a separate thread (different from **UI thread**), but the result from that code, when ready, will be delivered in `onPostExecute`.
i.e. The method `execute` returns the `AynscTask` itself,not `String` so change your code as

```
   ProsesTampil p = new ProsesTampil();
     xResult = p.execute(urltampil);
```

to

```
ProsesTampil p = new ProsesTampil();
p.execute(urltampil);
```

And get xResult  in `onPostExecute` method as

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            xResult = result;

        }
```

Comment: I tried using this and when I try to System.out.println(xResult) (the one onPostExecute) it shows the right value but it shows "null" here "JSONArray menuitemArray = new JSONArray(xResult)"

Comment: @user2913703 is casting problem  solved,then accept it so it may help others also,and post your other problems as new question

Answer (score 0):

`execute()` doesn't return a string.  So you can't assign it like that.  `AsyncTasks` are asynchronous-  they don't finish until later.  Any code you'd want to run on the result of an `AsyncTask` should be placed in the `onPostExecute()` function of the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: You ment: Any code you'd want to run on the result of `doInBackground` should be placed in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Correct.  That's what I get for answering questions at 2 am  :)

Answer (score 0):

First Thing You can not return value from `onPostExecute()` because return type is `void`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
```

Second Your class doesn't Return any value...

So if you want to get value of result try to get value from `onPostExecute()`.

I mean to say do as follow..

```
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                xResult = result;
                super.onPostExecute();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it because AsyncTask works in background thread.
Your result will come in UI thread after background has done self work:

```
   @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           //String result - that what you need     
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo can use

`String results = yourAsyntask.get()` instead of  using `yourAsyntask.execut()e` method, it will return you result. same as  Result get you in `onPostExecute`  method;

```
But it will block your main thread.
```

Comment: then what is the meaning of using asynctask,if it block main thread?

Comment: it will give serial execution benefits. and thats why i am mention it.